# How to encode hex in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm tring to write equivalent for `encode("hex")` in python3.

Here what i got:

```
s = "'"
print(str(s).encode('hex'))
>>27
```

Tring `binascii` in `Python 2.7`:

```
import binascii

s = "'"
print(binascii.hexlify(str(s)))
>>27
```

So in `Python 2.7` both methods give same result.  Now i tring to run this code in `Python 3.5`:

```
import binascii

s = "'"
print(binascii.hexlify(str(s)))

>>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

After i tried:

```
import binascii

s = "'"
print(binascii.hexlify(str(s).encode('utf8')))

>>b'27'
```

But not sure what i have to do next. How to get my `27`?

Comment: `s` is already a string, so no need to `str` it; instead, as per the message, you need to make it a "bytes-like object".

Comment: try `binascii.hexlify(s.encode('utf8')).decode()`

Comment: or `codecs.encode(s.encode('utf-8'),"hex").decode()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to decode it, like this:

```py
binascii.hexlify(str(s).encode('utf8')).decode('utf8')
```